# bindValueできない

Tags: php, pdo

prepareしたSQLにデータを実際にセットしようとしても、プレースホルダーにセットされません。

例えば、以下のコードでは、

```
$db = new DB();
$db->get("users",array($field, "=" , "ken");
```

```
SELECT * FROM users where name = "ken"
```

というSQLを作りたいのですが、コード中のコメントのbindValue前でもvindValue後のvar_dumpでも、

```
object(PDOStatement)#6 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(38) "SELECT * FROM 　　
users WHERE username = ?" }
```

となっていて、? がkenに置き換わりません。
どのようにしたら良いでしょうか？
お願いします。

DBクラス

```
public function query($sql , $params = array()){

$this->_error = false;
if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
  $x = 1;
  if(count($params)){
    foreach($params as $param){
      //bindvalue前
      var_dump($this->_query);
      $this->_query->bindValue($x,$param,PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $x++;
      //bindvalue後
      var_dump($this->_query);
    }
  }
  if($this->_query->execute()){
    $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
  }else{
    $this->_error = true;
  }
}
return $this;
}

public function action($action,$table, $where = array()){
 if(count($where) === 3){
  $operators = array('=', '>', '<' ,'>=' ,'<=');
  $field = $where[0];
  $operator = $where[1];
  $value = $where[2];

  if(in_array($operator, $operators)){
    $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
    if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->count()){
      return $this;
    }
  }
}
return false;
}


public function get($table, $where){ 
  return $this->action("SELECT *",$table, $where);
}
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/73431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

その状態できちんと `bindValue()` できているのではないでしょうか？

プレースホルダにバインドした値はクエリとは別に保持され、別々にDBドライバに送信されます。ですから**クエリ中の `?` が置き換えられた様子をPHPで確認することはできません**。プレースホルダに対応したRDBMSであればDB側のログにもやはり `?` のまま出力されるでしょう。

文字列としてSQL中に埋め込む場合、一旦文字列として埋め込んで、DB側でまた文字列を解析して、という無駄な処理を行わなければいけません。また埋め込みロジックにバグがあればSQLインジェクションなどの攻撃を許してしまいます。プレースホルダを使ったパラメタライズドクエリはパラメータを別途渡すことで、これらの問題を解決しています。